# How to iterate over variables and build a single command to execute?

Tags: bash, shell, heroku

I have a bash script to remove some records from a remote database by their email.

```
for email in "$@"; do
heroku pg:psql << EOF
  DELETE FROM table1 WHERE email='$email';
  DELETE FROM table2 WHERE email='$email';
  DELETE FROM table2 WHERE email='$email';
EOF
done
```

And when I execute it, it works of course but I'm connecting multiple times to Heroku:

```
./scripts/delete-account.sh email1@example.com email2@example.com
---> Connecting to DATABASE_URL
DELETE 0
DELETE 0
DELETE 0
---> Connecting to DATABASE_URL
DELETE 0
DELETE 0
DELETE 0
```

Is there any way to firstly build this SQL statement and then execute it at once?

I know I can have an imperative approach, create a variable, modify it in a loop and then pass it to `pg:psql` command, but I don't think it's the best and the only way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the script to build *all* the SQL statements, then pipe that to the psql command?

```
$cat ./scripts/delete-account.sh
(for email in "$@"; do
  echo "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE email='"$email"';"
  echo "DELETE FROM table2 WHERE email='"$email"';"
  echo "DELETE FROM table2 WHERE email='"$email"';"
done) | heroku pg:psql
```

and then call it as:

`$./scripts/delete-account.sh email1@example.com email2@example.com`

Also, watch out for quoting, the shell does not interpolate inside single quotes

(try `email=a@b.com;echo '$email'` and see what happens).

Comment: It would be more convenient to have just a one script for that.